# how to dertermine a query is better than the other from oracle EXPLAIN PLAN

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am optimizing an oracle query. I found the cost of my new query is lower than the original one. I think my new query may have better performance than the old one. But lots of people on web say "the COST column cannot be used to compare execution plans".  So my question is how do you know the performance of one query is better than the other if you don't check the cost from the explain plan? Any other ways? Thanks!

Comment: If you want a guide about using `explain`, SO might be the wrong place.

Comment: @gary . . . A question about the specific query and two execution plans would be appropriate for Stack Overflow.  A general question about comparing execution plans is too broad.

Comment: This question is not too broad.  Usually `cost` is a bit worthless, but if you *only* have the explain plan to go by then cost is by definition the best way to compare plans.  Jonathan Lewis, who literally wrote the book on the cost based optimizer, has written about this this issue [here](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/cost-again/).   One relevant quote: "...it is perfectly valid to compare the cost of two queries to see which one the optimizer thinks will be faster but, thanks to limitations and defects in the optimizer it may not be entirely sensible to do so."

Answer (score 3):

Query plans are extremely useful animals.  In general, however, they are not a useful way to determine which of two queries are actually going to be more efficient.  There are exceptionally few instances where a human can take a look at two reasonable query plans and immediately know that one will be more efficient than the other.  If you can, that generally implies that something is deeply flawed with one of the plans (i.e. you see a table scan of a billion row table rather than an index access to grab the 10 rows you know you're interested in).

When it comes down to comparing two different plans, you need to focus on execution statistics.  Most of the time, measuring the actual logical I/O is the simplest yardstick.  You can get that by running `set autotrace on` in SQL*Plus or using the autotrace option in SQL Developer (F6 rather than F5 to run the query).  You can also measure the elapsed time but that often requires a bit more effort to produce reasonable benchmarks based on what fraction of the blocks are going to be in the various caches (database, operating system, SAN, etc.) when the query runs.  CPU time is likely to be a bit more stable across executions regardless of caching.  Occasionally, you'll want to measure some other statistic (i.e. the amount of data sent over the network if you're looking at optimizing queries involving database links).